# Upgrading Gradle Build Tools on older hotfix branches in VCS

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I noticed that when loading up your project in Android Studio (currently running 3.1 on Canary Channel), it likes to force you to upgrade Gradle Build Tools and sometimes Gradle itself when it detects it isn't using the latest. The 2 pieces I'm talking about are:

In the root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha03'
   }
}
```

And in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

Note that I do not specify `buildToolsVersion` in my Gradle scripts (According to [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html), this means it tries to use the latest version). I like not specifying it because it's 1 less version I have to continuously change in my Gradle scripts.

For the most part, my question is in regards to best practices. For our software, we tag versions we release to production with the mindset that we might need to go back and hotfix any of those releases. When going back to older hotfixes, should I allow Android Studio to upgrade build tools? Or should I prevent it from doing so (assuming I can, maybe by specifying `buildToolsVersion` manually)? If the latter case, I don't know how to keep Android Studio from continuously prompting me to upgrade in these cases. Sometimes it seems to fail syncing if I *don't* upgrade the build tools.

What's the best policy here and what are the functional differences between the two main choices I've outlined?

### EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of the prompt I get. It's worded in such a way that it sounds like a build will not be possible unless I upgrade the tools:

[image]

And if I click "Update manually" to prevent it from doing so, I get:

[image]

Comment: gradle-plugin and required gradle version table is here. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle And buildToolsVersion is not related to this, I think.

Comment: @Toris That explains the gradle upgrade, but what I'm still looking for is: Can newer android studio versions work with older Gradle Build Tools without requiring them to be upgraded? If so, what's the process for that? And assuming I can do it, is it even important for older hotfix branches?

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle > Android plugin 3.0.0 requires Gradle version 4.1 or higher. If you're opening an existing project using Android Studio 3.0 or later, follow the prompts to automatically update

Comment: My point is: Android Studio 3.0 != Android Gradle Plugin 3.0. True or false? If true, then Android Studio 3.0 upgrading to plugin 3.0 might be due to the build tools being upgraded (e.g. 26.0.2 or something). Sorry if I'm not being clear (or making sense).

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 != Android Gradle Plugin 3.0 is True. But I can use `buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"` `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip` with Android Studio 2.2.x.

Comment: Does that mean you are using Android Studio 2.3 (or a version number somewhat similar to the gradle build tools version you have shown (2.3.3))? Not sure if I'm going off on a tangent here... I'm still horribly confused. There's too many moving parts here. I don't know what's forcing upgrades of what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160141/discussion-between-toris-and-void-pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "Cancel and update manually" in update dialog suits your needs.
If canceled once, you can see the message in status line. (Please see test8)
Also, if you have selected to update, you can manually set it lower again, I think.

Selecting "Update manually" causes build error once, but no error seems to happen if build it again. Please see tests 6-8 below.

Selecting lower gradle plugin version also seems having no problem, as I've tested again from test2 after all tests done.

---

Updated 2017/12/12
Related resources (to check current version):

- Gradle
  [Gradle - releases](https://gradle.org/releases/)

  > Dec 06, 2017
  >   v4.4
- Gradle plugin (>= 3.0.0)
  NB: Please see [Add Build Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#gmaven-access) Programmatic access section for details.
  [Google's maven repo - master index](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/master-index.xml) `com.android.tools.build`
  [Google's maven repo - build tools group index](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/group-index.xml) `gradle`

  > 3.0.1 or 3.1.0-alpha05
- POM file url sample (for stable channel, >= 3.0.0):
  NB: These are one of paths that gradle will access to get files
  https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom or
  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
- POM file url sample (for alpha channel, >= 3.0.0):
  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0-alpha05/gradle-3.1.0-alpha05.pom
- Old gradle plugin (<= 2.3.x)
  [Maven repo - gradle artifacts](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle)

---

Below here for information:

To see versions:
Android Studio version: Help > About

Gradle plugin version:
build.gradle(Project)
sample: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha03'`

Gradle version:
gradle-wrapper.properties
sample: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip`

---

NB1: Each gradle plugin version has required Gradle version.
See the table in Update Gradle section of this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle).
For example: Gradle plugin 3.0.0 requires Gradle 4.1 or higher.

NB2: Some gradle plugin version has required buildToolsVersion, but basically having no relations to it.
For example: Gradle plugin [3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-0-0) requires buildToolsVersion 26.0.2 or higher.

NB3: Some gradle plugin version has release notes with "This is a minor update to support Android Studio xxx"
For example: In the section of Gradle plugin [3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-0-0)

> 3.0.1 (November 2017)
>   This is a minor update to support Android Studio 3.0.1

---

I used same buildToolsVersion (27.0.1) for all tests below.
Android Studio: 2.2.x is 2.2.3 I think.
I used (android-studio-ide-171.4408382-windows) for Android Studio 3.0.x. 
,not current one, but I've already downloaded it ago.

---

Test 1:

Android Studio: 2.2.x
Gradle plugin: 2.3.3
Gradle: 3.3
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: jcenter()

build: pass

---

Test 2:

Android Studio: 3.0.x
Gradle plugin: 2.3.3
Gradle: 3.3
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: jcenter()

build: pass

NB: When changing Android Studio version from 2.2.x to 3.0.x for same project, I saw an update dialog, but not the one in the question.
I've selected "Show tomorrow" for it.

---

Test 3:

Android Studio: 3.0.x
Gradle plugin: 2.3.3
Gradle: 4.2.1
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: jcenter()

build: pass

---

Test 4:

Android Studio: 3.0.x
Gradle plugin: 3.0.1
Gradle: 4.2.1
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: jcenter()

build: failed

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
...
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
```

NB: Have to change repository settings.

---

Test 5:

Android Studio: 3.0.x
Gradle plugin: 3.0.1
Gradle: 4.2.1
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: google()

build: passed

---

Test 6:

Android Studio: 3.0.x
Gradle plugin: 3.0.0-alpha9
Gradle: 4.2.1
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: google()

Update dialog is shown.
build: failed after choosing "Cancel and update manually"

[image: Update dialog]

In message window:
Error:The project is using an incompatible version of the Android Gradle plugin.
Please update your project to use version 3.0.0.
Search in build.gradle files

[image]

NB: This is because gradle plugin 3.0.0 or higher is already released.

---

Test 7:

Android Studio: 3.0.x
Gradle plugin: 3.1.0-alpha03
Gradle: 4.2.1
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: google()

Update dialog is NOT shown.
build: failed

Event log:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.4-3.
```

NB1: Have to add kotlin.
NB2: kotlin requires mavenCentral repository.
See [Kotlin - Using Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)

---

Test 8:

Android Studio: 3.0.x
Gradle plugin: 3.1.0-alpha03
Gradle: 4.2.1
buildToolsVersion: 27.0.1
buildscript/repositories: google(), mavenCentral()

Update dialog is NOT shown.
build: passed
A message is shown in status line when I click classpath...gradle line in build.config, but no problem.

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha03'
//      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
//      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
//      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
//      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
//      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5.1-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

Status line
"A newer version of com.android.tools.build:gradle than 3.1.0-alpha03 is available: 3.1.0-alpha04"
[image]

Comment: I was hoping Android Studio automatically notifies me of the new versions for update. Thanks for that. Where can I get the latest version numbers from?

Comment: @RJFares Group index of `com.android.tools.build` in Google's repo has such information. Please see my updates.